# Run (JS) function if server responded something specific

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, response

On one of my pages I have "tracking.php" that makes a request to another server, and if tracking is sucessful in Firebug Net panel I see the response `trackingFinished();`

Is there an easy way (built-in function) to accomplish something like this:

```
If ("tracking.php" responded "trackingFinished();") { *redirect*... }
```

Javascript? PHP? Anything?

The thing is, this "tracking.php" also creates browser and flash cookies (and then responds with trackingfinished(); when they're created). I had a JS that did something like this:

```
If ("MyCookie" is created) { *redirect*... }
```

It worked, but if you had MyCookie in your browser from before, it just redirected before "track.php" had the time to create new cookies, so old cookies didn't get overwritten (which I'm trying to accomplish) before the redirection...

The solution I have in mind is to redirect after trackingFinished(); was responded...

Comment: just check the response body to get the `trackingFinished();` or it might be that this is being sent in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better form in javascript to make request from one page to another, without leaving the first is with the ajax method, and this one jQuery make it so easy, you only have to use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, and pass a little parameters:

```
$.post(url, {parameter1: parameter1value, param2: param2value})
```

And you can concatenate some actions:

```
$.post().done(function(){}).fail(function(){})
```

And isntead of the ajax, you can use the [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) that is more easy, and use the done and fail method to evaluate the succes of the information recived

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, AJAX is the best way to communicate between pages like this. Here's an example of an AJAX request to your track.php page. It uses the success function to see if track.php returned 'trackingFinished();'. If it did then it redirects the page 'redirect.php':

```
$.ajax({
    url: "track.php",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        if(data === 'trackingFinished();'){
            document.location = 'redirect.php';
        }
    }
});
```

The example uses JQuery.